# Print multiple lines in a text_area_tag in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, textarea

I have a loop for comments that I want to print in a text_area_tag.  Here is my code

```
<%=text_area_tag 'body', nil, rows: 10, cols: 25%>
<% @comments.each do |comment|%>
<p><%=comment.user_name%> says: <%=comment.comment%></p>
<%end%>
```

What I am trying to do is, instead of printing out all the comments in the p tags, I want to print them inside the text_area_tag

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Rails helpers like `simple_format`

```
<% @comments.each do |comment| %>
  <p><%=comment.user_name%> says: <%= simple_format comment.comment %></p>
<% end %>
```

Other helpers you may be wanting to experiment with: (text = comment.comment)

```
<%= raw text %>
<%= h text %>
<%= text.html_safe %>
```